# Where do I find the snippet gallery on SP 2013 Online?

Tags: office-365

I'm trying to modify the placement of a search snippet by moving the code in the snippet gallery to custom HTML code in the master page template. (I'd like the search bar to be included in the custom menu I've created)

I'm following the instructions here but I'm unable to find the "Snippets" button as per the instructions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822367(v=office.15).aspx

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong.

We have Office 365 so I'm using SP 2013 online.

Comment: Can you see design manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Using gear icon select `Design Manager`
2. From left navigation select `Edit Master Pages`
3. Click on any of the master page for ex: oslo
4. On the preview page you can see a top ribbon which contains `Snippets` link

Comment: dude you kill it on here! Congrats on getting such a high score in only a month!

Comment: @Colbs Tx :) I have one tab dedicated to StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

I found it, very complicated. Not sure if there's a better way...

From Design Manager I clicked "Publish and Apply Design". From that page I went to the Master Page Gallery page. Navigating through the folders to find where my master page is stored I clicked on the **HTML** file associated with my master page and from the drop down menu options "view properties". Here I found a hyperlink .html which I clicked for an in-browser preview. At the top there is a link to the snippets.

It seems this should be easier to find ...

Comment: Can you follow the steps I have outlined?

Comment: No. From Design Manager > Edit Master Pages I cannot see the title of the documents so I'm not sure which would be the master page. I thought this may have been a result of my custom Master Page so I switched it back to Oslo and have the same issues. The name column for all files is left blank. Is this normal?

Comment: @iliketolearn once you publish an HTML Master page from Master Page gallery it will appear in the (3) step I outlined below.